# date picker and timer picker in one input text

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

is there a way to combine time picker and date picker in one text I've seen a couple of answers like this one http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/sSqKz/ (this is by sir gatores) but its only date i want to record a start date and time and end date and time so i was wondering if you can combine them. one input text has one datepicker and one timepicker

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){       
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>        
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>          
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
                <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>                
            </div>

            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

update:

found this http://jsfiddle.net/bk7fK/1/ see it its good but i cant make it run..any idea why i cant make this fiddle run i think im missing a js but i dont know what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see time picker in your code.

**FYI:** *default jQuery date picker doesn't allow time picker*, for that you need another plugin along with jQuery.

Check this [jQuery Timepicker Addon](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon)

Here is a [demo](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle of that?sort of struggling without a sample so you mean i have to make two different input one for date and one for time?too bad

Comment: @satinekianne No. Have you checked my demo?

Comment: hey i found the demo..there is an input with time and date together i hope i can work with it any idea on how to make this work you can give any idea to me?because the code is missing..basic example 3 is perfect for any idea on this one?